# NetworkStatsManager for get mobile data Android issue

Tags: android

i am using NetworkStatsManager in 6.0 for getting mobile data and using this method

```
 public long getAllRxBytesMobile1(Context context) {
    NetworkStats.Bucket bucket;
    try {
        bucket = networkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,
                getSubscriberId(context, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE),
                0,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        return -1;
    }
    return bucket.getRxBytes();
}
```

and

```
private String getSubscriberId(Context context, int networkType) {
    if (ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE == networkType) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return tm.getSubscriberId();
    }
    return "";
}
```

but returning always zero. how to resolved that?

Comment: display RemoteException e in log may be you gitting some exception

Comment: okk wait ...let me check ...

Comment: E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
 E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
only showing this in log

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int slotIndex = 1;
int subscriptionId = SubscriptionManager.from(mContext).getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(slotIndex).getSubscriptionId();
try {
    Class c = Class.forName("android.telephony.TelephonyManager");
    Method m = c.getMethod("getSubscriberId", new Class[] {int.class});
    Object o = m.invoke(telephonyManager, new Object[]{subscriptionId});

    String subscriberId = (String) o;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: subscriber id getting properly i also checked this code but result getting zero still

Comment: long getTxBytes()
Number of bytes transmitted during the bucket's time interval.

long getRxBytes()
Number of bytes received during the bucket's time interval.

Comment: use getTxBytes()..may be you are not receiving bytes so check for transmitting bytes if any

Comment: how can i check transmitting bytes? i have no any idea for that.